# Fresh install of widows 10 on new SSD keep files from Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage

I just ordered my first SSD ever and currently have a 1TB hard drive with a lot of media files that i want to keep. I want to do a fresh install of windows, since my current install is very slow and cluttered. So my question is how do i go about keeping like 300gb+ of movies from my TB hard drive while removing windows etc from it to get more space for movies and games in the future? is my only option to move them over to my SSD while reformatting my hard drive and move them back over after?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all the Windows files, everything but your files you want to keep.

Assuming it is a desktop PC:

Shut down and remove power cord, hold the power button for 15 seconds, open the pc and Disconnect the old drive cables inside the computer, connect your new drive and install windows, once The new install of windows boots and works, shut down and re-connect the old drive to the motherboard (you may need an additional data data cable to do this), boot from the new drive and delete the files from the old drive, done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a**lot of empty space** in your Old HDD, you can **split it** into 2 particions. One particion will contain all the data including your windows installation and the second will be empty. You can do this easily on Windows 10 via the "Drive manager". Then you want to move all the files you need to the second particion. After that you install windows on your new SSD, format the first particion of your old hard drive. This enables you to keep your data while "cleaning" all the rest. You can also do this without the SSD drive. 
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As it was suggested above, for **desktop** - just install new SSD into the box and deploy new Windows on it. Then from Windows you can transfer the files to SSD volume. Windows folder on HDD can be removed.

For **laptop** - install new SSD instead of HDD and deploy new Windows on it. Then use USB to SATA adapter to connect HDD as an external disk and transfer the files to SSD volume.